# How to build an alarm clock/reminder function in LWUIT?

Tags: lwuit, alarm, codenameone

I'd like to implement an alarm clock/reminder function in a Lwuit application, where the user may set an alarm time, and at that time a reminder dialog pops up with an alarm sound. However, I'm unsure about the approach. So help on any of the below questions would be greatly appreciated:

- How to keep a timer running constantly, no matter what Form is displayed, e.g. without interfering with lwuit and EDT?
- What's the right way to implement the trigger mechanism that will make the reminder Dialog box pop up? This may happen at any time, no matter what Form is currently displayed and shouldn't interfere with the ongoing user operation, so that when the reminder dialog is closed the user can continue whereever he was when the reminder popped up.
- And finally, when the application is closed, or not running in the foreground, how can I keep a timer running? With the new and exiting CodenameOne coming up, I'd obviously like the solution to work on both J2ME, iOS and Android.

Sorry, if the answers are obvious, but I haven't been able to find a solid working solution.

Answer (score 2):

1) You can use java.util.Timer for a generic timer, its callbacks will occur off the EDT so in order to use LWUIT you would just need to callback into the EDT using `Display.getInstance().callSerially()` and have your code within the `Runnable` callback.

2) In order to not block input and display in an unobtrusive way you can use the glasspane to just show a translucent element on top of the screen. It will not block input in any way. There is a sample of that in the LWUIT Chat demo application.

3) You can't. Background process execution isn't really supported on any device, all devices have a special "use case based" solution for background execution which requires you to write your applications in a very specific way. [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/) will add support for push notification which will allow you to push an alarm from your server. Seams counter intuitive at first but if you consider the amount of battery life that will be taken up by background processes it becomes pretty obvious why this was done.

Comment: Thanks Shai! It's amazing how you find time to answer all these questions.

Comment: About 1) This is actually the type of solution I tried, but I must have gotten the details wrong. I'll try a bit harder now I know it's the right path ;-) About 2) I hadn't thought about using glasspane. However, it's OK that the input is blocked, so I guess a Dialog (called from EDT) would an OK solution. Maybe it didn't work due to my problems with 1). I'll also have a look at the Chat demo. About 3) I guess that was the answer I was afraid I'd get ;-) But the server solution sounds interesting - is it something already available in lwuit?

Comment: Push notification won't be available in LWUIT. Even in Codename One we will only support it on smartphones and not on J2ME devices since there is nothing that we can do on such devices without an operator/manufacturer signature which is IMPOSSIBLE to get.